# Chart.js only displays on refresh in Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, canvas, chart.js

I've managed to create a chart in my Rails app using Chart.js, however for some reason, the graph doesn't display when the view loads for the first time. If I refresh the page, it displays correctly and I can't work out why. Any suggestions?

statement.html.erb:

```
....
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="height:350px">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var data = [
      {
          value: gon.creditTotal,
          color:"#F7464A",
          highlight: "#FF5A5E",
          label: "Red"
      },
      {
          value: gon.assetTotal ,
          color: "#46BFBD",
          highlight: "#5AD3D1",
          label: "Green"
      }
  ];

  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);
</script>
```

**note**: I've tried wrapping the javascript inside the following but I still get the same issue:

```
window.onload  = function(){
***here***
}
```

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require Chart
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails',                '4.2.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',       '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails',           '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier',             '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',         '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails',         '4.0.3'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 4.2.1'
gem 'turbolinks',           '2.3.0'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder',             '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',                 '0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'chart-js-rails'
gem 'gon'
```

Comment: Perhaps it's trying to find an ID on the page before it's fully loaded. Maybe try wrapping `document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");` in a `document.ready` function?

Comment: @RyanRebo That's what I think but if I wrap everything from the javascript inside window.onload  = function(){ ***here*** }, I still get the same issue.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with turbolinks, try removing it from `application.js` and see if the problem is still there.

Comment: Yes, removing turbolinks appears to resolve my issue.

Comment: Did you manage to get working with turbolinks? I tried using

 <meta name="turbolinks-cache-control" content="no-cache">

in the page header, but it did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I got working my chart.js with turbolinks

```
    var ready = function() {

  $.ajax({
        url: "myurl.json",
        type: "get",
        async: true,
        datatype : 'string'
        }).done (function (data) {

          var years = [];
          var obstaravania = [];
          var trzby = [];
          var zisk = [];
          var obstarcolor=[];
          var trzbycolor=[];
          var ziskcolor=[];
      for(var i in data) {
        years.push(data[i].year);
        obstaravania.push(data[i].obstaravanie);
        trzby.push(data[i].trzby);
        zisk.push(data[i].zisk);
        obstarcolor.push('#c0392b');
        trzbycolor.push('#337ab7');
        ziskcolor.push('#27ae60');
      }
      var chartdata = {
        labels: years,
        datasets : [
          {
            label: 'Obstarávania',
            backgroundColor: obstarcolor,
            labelColor: [ '#c0392b'],
            data: obstaravania
          },
          {
           label: 'Tržby',
           backgroundColor:trzbycolor,
            labelColor: [ '#337ab7'],
           data: trzby 
          },
          {
           label: 'Zisk',
            backgroundColor:ziskcolor,
          labelColor: [ '#27ae60'], 
           data: zisk 
          }
        ]
      };
    var barOptions = {
        responsive: true
    };
      var ctx2 = $("#mychart");
    var newchart = new Chart(ctx2, {type: 'bar', data: chartdata, options:barOptions});
    });

  //});

};
 $(".contractors.showcontractor").ready(ready);
  document.addEventListener('turbolinks:before-cache', function() {
    if ($('#mychart').width >1) {newchart.destroy() ;}
     });
  $(".contractors.showcontractor").on('turbolinks:ready', ready);
```